# desktop development or web development?

Tags: c#, desktop

am a c# developer for about 2 years now...am a desktop developer and have been working with desktop apps for the past two years ...my question is should i complete in the desktop development or should i move to the web development...to be honest my knowlodge in web development is very poor ...if the answer is yes what should i study and  what to start with
..

Answer (score 5):

```
bool condition1 = IfILikeWebDevelopment ();

bool condition2 = IfWebDevelopmentCareerPromisingWhereILive ();

if (condition1 || condition2)
{
    Go ();
}
```

Comment: I think an && would be much more suited, you can't have good web development without liking it.

Comment: I agree. As with everything you do, to be fond of what you do is very important.

Comment: its not a matter of love or hate ..at the beginning i studied both web and desktop programming...but all my work after studying was desktop so it wasn't much like a choice for me....

Answer (score 2):

It never hurts to know more about what you're doing. Sure; learn web development. Try a little php and Ruby, while you're at it.

As for how to start with ASP.Net, just dive in. Create a new ASP.Net project in Visual Studio and start making changes. There are a ton of tutorial sites out there for getting started ([here for example](http://www.dotnetspider.com/)).

Comment: +1. I think knowing different technologies/languages is a big plus. You don't HAVE to use it, but knowing what it's all about is very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely it is worth to know how to build web applications!

1. Make yourself familiar with [XHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/xhtml/DEFAULT.asp) + [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/default.asp), so you will have good understanding what your web app have to produce
2. Learn from good patterns: start with [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/MVC/) if you want to stick with C#

And you're done :)

Answer (score 1):

Do at home whichever one you're not doing at work.

Answer (score 0):

It won't hurt knowing something about web development actually with asp.net you almost have the same programming model as win forms so you will feel home :)

but really you should make your decision based on what helps you in your carrer

Answer (score 0):

What is better for your carreer and for your pleasure is to become a better programmer... improving your programming skills and your experience.

Base your choice on the opportunity to work with more experienced programmers, on the qualify of life in the position, on the possibility of personal development.

After two years of C#, if you are willing to learn, try to learn a little bit more about OO theory. Dig into the concepts, they last longer than the languages.

Comment: yes am willing to learn ..maybe a phd in computer science will be a good target ...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the scale and the persistance model needed?

The biggest technical differentiators between the web and desktop is the underlying persistence model and your user interaction model.

With the web, you are going to need a database and stick to the web pattern (unless you want to do Ajax, in which case learn desktop).

With the desktop, you are going to learn how to make applications. However, if the application you want to make can also be done on the web, then don't bother and just use the web. Also, you have a lot more freedom on the desktop which comes as a dangerous proposition for employers these days.

I would recommend that you focus on improving on core algorithms and datastructures, and you should focus on what you enjoy doing with your strengths in mind.